# Why does the thread freeze my code in my actionListener implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, try-catch, actionlistener

I am trying to make an oval move smoothly by taping the buttons (up,down,...)and I try to use threads with the try and catch it's work inside the class but when I use it here it freezes the whole app.

```
class movingdown implements ActionListener{
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for (int i = 0; i < frame.getWidth(); i++) {
            x++;
            frame.repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    }
}//movingdown end
```

Here is my whole code:

```
package swingWork;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
public class movingball {
JFrame frame;
int x=0;
int y =0;
public static void main(String []args){
    movingball ball = new movingball();
    ball.start();

}
public void start(){
    ballDrawer drawer = new ballDrawer();   
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton up =new JButton("UP");
    JButton down =new JButton("DOWN");
    JButton left =new JButton("LEFT");
    JButton right =new JButton("RIGHT");

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, up);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, down);   
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, left);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, right);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawer);
    //setting up the action listener:

    up.addActionListener(new movingup());
    down.addActionListener(new movingdown());
    left.addActionListener(new movingleft());
    right.addActionListener(new movingright());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
int rightsize =right.getWidth();



}//start method end


//here we have the listeners

class movingup implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int i = x; i > frame.getHeight(); i--) {
        x=i;
        try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception ex){}
    }
    }

}//moving up end
class movingdown implements ActionListener{
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for (int i = 0; i < frame.getWidth(); i++) {
            x++;
            frame.repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    }
}//movingdown end
class movingleft implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


            x=x+10;
            frame.repaint();

        System.out.println(x);

    }
}//moving  left end
class movingright implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
}//moving right end


class ballDrawer extends JPanel{
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);


    }//PaintComponents End


}//ball drawer class end

}//main class end
```

Comment: Because Swing is busy waiting for your ActionListener to return before it does anything else.

Answer (score 3):

### You never, ever, EVER want to use `Thread.sleep()` on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). EVER!!

It never accomplishes anything good, and it makes your screen freeze until the sleep is over. So don't do it!!

The best way to animate in Swing is to use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to fire events that change your drawing properties periodically. This happens on a different thread so the screen stays responsive. You can set this timer to run all the time, but have it do nothing when the circle should not be moving. Here's the code for the `Timer`'s `ActionListener`

```
t = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(deltaX == 1 && x >= frame.getWidth() - CIRCLE_WIDTH) deltaX = 0;
    if(deltaY == 1 && y >= frame.getHeight() - CIRCLE_HEIGHT) deltaY = 0;
    if(deltaX == -1 && x <= 0) deltaX = 0;
    if(deltaY == -1 && y <= 0) deltaY = 0;
    x += deltaX;
    y += deltaY;
    if(deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0) {
      frame.repaint();
    }
  }
});
t.start();
```

Then, your buttons just tell the timer to animate in the correct direction by setting the delta value, e.g.

```
class movingup implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    deltaY = -1;
  }
}// moving up end
```

As you can see, I create a timer object inside `start` method, and just tell the timer to start animating by pressing the button. The timer has it's own, different `ActionListener` (implemented as an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) here) that actually tells the parameters to change and then repaints if something has moved. You could optimize it further by telling Swing to only redraw the part of the screen that needs redrawing with [`JComponent.repaint(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(java.awt.Rectangle)), but this is just an example. If you do this, make sure the repaint is large enough to get **both** where the circle *was* and where it is now.

Here's the complete program, including the constants `CIRCLE_WIDTH` and `CIRCLE_HEIGHT`, the new timer logic, and all four buttons changed:

```
package swingWork;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class movingball {
  private static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 100;
  private static final int CIRCLE_HEIGHT = 100;
  private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 50;

  JFrame frame;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int deltaX = 0;
  int deltaY = 0;
  Timer t;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    movingball ball = new movingball();
    ball.start();

  }

  public void start() {
    ballDrawer drawer = new ballDrawer();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton up = new JButton("UP");
    JButton down = new JButton("DOWN");
    JButton left = new JButton("LEFT");
    JButton right = new JButton("RIGHT");

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, up);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, down);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, left);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, right);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawer);
    // setting up the action listener:

    up.addActionListener(new movingup());
    down.addActionListener(new movingdown());
    left.addActionListener(new movingleft());
    right.addActionListener(new movingright());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    t = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(deltaX == 1 && x == frame.getWidth() - CIRCLE_WIDTH) deltaX = 0;
        if(deltaY == 1 && y == frame.getHeight() - CIRCLE_HEIGHT) deltaY = 0;
        if(deltaX == -1 && x == 0) deltaX = 0;
        if(deltaY == -1 && y == 0) deltaY = 0;
        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;
        if(deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0) {
          frame.repaint();
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();

  }// start method end

  // here we have the listeners

  class movingup implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      deltaY = -1;
    }
  }// moving up end

  class movingdown implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      deltaY = 1;
    }
  }// movingdown end

  class movingleft implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      deltaX = -1;
    }
  }// moving left end

  class movingright implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      deltaX = 1;
    }
  }// moving right end

  class ballDrawer extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillOval(x, y, CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_HEIGHT);

    }// PaintComponents End

  }// ball drawer class end

}// main class endreading: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15511282/1768232
```

Comment: As a matter of personal opinion, I'd update the position and then do you range check otherwise it's possible for the ball to leave the bounds for a frame ;)

Answer (score 3):

As, has already been pointed out, you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is preventing the UI from been updated until your loop and method exit

A better solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, which generates regular callbacks to a `ActionListener` within the context of the EDT, allowing you to safely update the UI from within it.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

You should also be calling `super.paintComponent`, which, amongst other things, will fill the background of the `Graphcis` context for your automatically.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Movingball {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Movingball ball = new Movingball();
                ball.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private BallDrawer drawer;

    public void start() {
        drawer = new BallDrawer();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton up = new JButton("UP");
        JButton down = new JButton("DOWN");
        JButton left = new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton right = new JButton("RIGHT");

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, up);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, down);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, left);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, right);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawer);
        // setting up the action listener:

        up.addActionListener(new Movingup());
        down.addActionListener(new Movingdown());
        left.addActionListener(new Movingleft());
        right.addActionListener(new Movingright());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }// start method end

    // here we have the listeners
    class Movingup implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawer.moveUp();
        }
    }// moving up end

    class Movingdown implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawer.moveDown();
        }
    }// movingdown end

    class Movingleft implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawer.moveLeft();
        }
    }// moving left end

    class Movingright implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawer.moveRight();
        }
    }// moving right end

    public static class BallDrawer extends JPanel {

        public static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 100;
        public static final int CIRCLE_HEIGHT = 100;

        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        private int xPos;
        private int yPos;

        public BallDrawer() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += xDelta;
                    yPos += yDelta;

                    if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                        xDelta = 0;
                    } else if (xPos + CIRCLE_WIDTH > getWidth()) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - CIRCLE_WIDTH;
                        xDelta = 0;
                    }
                    if (yPos < 0) {
                        yPos = 0;
                        yDelta = 0;
                    } else if (yPos + CIRCLE_HEIGHT > getHeight()) {
                        yPos = getHeight() - CIRCLE_HEIGHT;
                        yDelta = 0;
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void moveLeft() {
            xDelta = -1;
        }

        public void moveRight() {
            xDelta = 1;
        }

        public void moveUp() {
            yDelta = -1;
        }

        public void moveDown() {
            yDelta = 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, CIRCLE_WIDTH, CIRCLE_HEIGHT);

        }// PaintComponents End

    }// ball drawer class end

}// main class end
```

You should also isolate functionality to the class responsible for actually managing it, in this your `BallDrawer` should be managing the movement of the ball, not the other class, this allows it to be self contained and re-usable.

Comment: This example also isolates all the responsibility for the management of the `BallDrawer` to the class itself.  It's also why this is a community post ;)

Answer (score -2):

The for loops are causing a lot of lag. Try restructuring your code like this.

```
public class MovingBall{
    String direction;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create your frame and buttons...
        upButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener{
            direction = "up";
        });
        //repeat this actionListener to the other buttons
        while (true){
            try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            drawer.repaint();
        }
    }
    public class Drawer extends JPanel{
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            if(direction.equals("up")) {
                y = y - 5;
            }
            //repeat the if statement with the other directions
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0,0,frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not calling the Thread.sleep() method on the event dispatch thread... I'm calling it after all the ActionListener are created and I'm calling Thread.sleep() to periodically refresh the drawer. @durron597

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected, you're not calling it in the Event Dispatch Thread, but regardless, this code doesn't allow the JVM to exit gracefully, it just creates an infinite loop that will choke your framerate.

Comment: I use this method in my programs and it allows for a smooth framerate and its pretty easy to understand. It may not give the best framerate, but its okay to make a little ball animation @durron597

Comment: How do you know what thread main is called in? You've also broken the paint chain and as a general recommendation, you shouldn't be overriding paint

Comment: @MadProgrammer Should I override paintComponent instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer but what is the difference between the two? Does paintComponent paint the component quicker?

Comment: `paintComponent` is generally encouraged and `paint` has a more complex job to perform (paint the background, border and children).  If you perform custom painting before calling `paint`, what you've painted is removed, if you call it after, it "might" paint over the children.  `paintComponent` just has a simpler job to do and generally reduces the "weirdness" that might occur...